# Streaming webm with ffserver error-

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, webm, ffserver

I have setup ffserver to stream mpeg-ts, flv from a live rtsp feed via ffmpeg, but when i also include webm format in the configuration and try to play the webm file in browser i get the following error in the log

"Only VP8,VP9 video and Vorbis,Opus(experimental, use -strict -2) audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM"

The ffmpeg command i use is 
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.1:5543/lowQ.sdp -c copy http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx:8080/feed1.ffm

The ffserver configuration is

Feed feed1.ffm
Format webm
NoAudio
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
VideoBitRate 500k
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoFrameRate 25
VideoCodec libvpx
StartSendOnKey
Preroll 15

Appreciate your help in this!

Answer (score 0):

try to compile ffmpeg with libvpx support (../configure --enable-libvpx)